# CSS, z-index DIV´S should overlay other DIV on hover

Tags: html, css, z-index

my problem is that i have 2 divs div A has z-index=10 and divB z-index=9 div B is partially below div A but i cant get hover option on div B since z-index is low so any solution please help

Comment: Have you tried increasing it?

Comment: I tried to replicate your problem and it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/j25eq8vp/

Comment: Please always include your code and also if you can include a working jsfiddle.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the hover isnt fired... cause div-A is on the top layer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.,

```
#divA{
   width:200px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    height:100px;
    z-index: 10;
}

#divB{
    width:200px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
     height:100px;
     z-index: 9
}
#divB:hover{
    background-color: #0082ff;
}

<div id="divA"></div>
<div id="divB"></div>
```